# Как сделать метод универсальным, чтобы он мог работать с разными типами объектов в PHP

Tags: php, ооп

Подскажите, как грамотно решить следующую задачу.
Есть два класса и интерфейс

```
  class LeadAskQuestion implements iLead
    {
        private string $userName;
        private string $userTelephone;
        private string $userEmail;
        private string $userQuestion;
    
        
        public function __construct(string $userName, string $userTelephone, string $userEmail, string $userQuestion)
        {
            $this->userName = $userName;
            $this->userTelephone = $userTelephone;
            $this->userEmail = $userEmail;
            $this->userQuestion = $userQuestion;
        }
    
        public function getLead()
        {
            return [
                "userName" => $this->userName,
                "userName" => $this->userTelephone,
                "userName" => $this->userEmail,
                "userName" => $this->userQuestion,
            ]
        }
    }


    class LeadReview implements iLead
    {
        private string $userName;
        private string $userTelephone;
        private string $userEmail;
        private string $userReview;
        private string $userPhoto;
    

        public function __construct(string $userName, string $userTelephone, string $userEmail, string $userReview, string $userPhoto)
        {
            $this->userName = $userName;
            $this->userTelephone = $userTelephone;
            $this->userEmail = $userEmail;
            $this->userReview = $userReview;
            $this->userPhoto = $userPhoto;
        }
    
        public function getLead()
        {
            return [
                "userName" => $this->userName,
                "userTelephone" => $this->userTelephone,
                "userEmail" => $this->userEmail,
                "userReview" => $this->userReview,
                "userPHoto" => $this->userPhoto,
            ];
        }
    }

    interface iLead {
        public function getLead();
    }
```

У меня есть метод leadAddCrm, который работает с сторонним API метом crm.lead.add.

```
class Bitrix24Sender
{
    private array $headers;
    private array $webHookUrl;

    public function __construct(string $webHookUrl)
    {
        $this->headers = array('Accept' => 'application/json');
        $this->webHookUrl = $webHookUrl;
    }

    public function leadCrmAdd(Lead $lead) // TODO Как Сделать параметр метода универсальным, чтобы он умел добавлять любой тип лида?
    {
        $url = $this->webHookUrl;
        $parameters = [
            "fields" => [
                "TITLE" => "Тайтл Лида",
                "NAME" => "Андрей",
                "SECOND_NAME" => "Викторович",
                "LAST_NAME" => "Пушкин"
            ]
        ];

        $request = \Requests::post($url, $this->headers, $parameters);
        return $request;
    }
}
```

Для того, чтобы метод стороннего сервиса заработал, ему нужно передавать json с опреденными названиями полей. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы мой метод leadcrmadd "знал", какие поля конкретного объекта нужно взять, чтобы правильно спарсить их и передать в чужой API. Я бы мог написать if и проверить, что объект принадлежит указанному классу и отправлять запрос нужным мне образом, но мне кажется есть гораздо лучшее решение. В ООП, если я правильно понимаю, это называется полиморфизмом.

**Я знаю, что здесь можно было вынести общие поля в отдельный класс и наследоваться от него, но в рамках текущей задачи это не очень удачное решение. Класс Lead постоянно меняется, сегодня у него будут одни поля, а завтра другие. На самом деле у них нету ничего общего.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас оба класса LeadReview и LeadAskQuestion реализуют общий интерфейс iLead, поэтому вы можете передавать в функцию ***public function leadCrmAdd()*** зависимость не от конкретного экзепляра класса, а от интерфейса iLead
**public function leadCrmAdd(iLead $lead)**. В таком случае, можно будет передавать в параметры любой класс, который наследует интерфейс iLead

```
use namespacepath/iLead; 

public function leadCrmAdd(iLead $lead)
    {
        $url = $this->webHookUrl;
        $parameters = [
            "fields" => [
                "TITLE" => "Тайтл Лида",
                "NAME" => "Андрей",
                "SECOND_NAME" => "Викторович",
                "LAST_NAME" => "Пушкин"
            ]
        ];

        $request = \Requests::post($url, $this->headers, $parameters);
        return $request;
    }
```